# Best way to stop async process in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I need to implement a function in javascript that runs an async process in the next way:

1. The process will run async checking if a variable is set to true
2. When true, the async process will stop
3. When the variables is set to false, the async process will start again.

What is the best aproach? A global variable that is accesible for both functions (the async and the UI) or via callbacks?

Comment: "checking if a variable is set to true"
Best solution is to use event emmiter

Comment: The project only uses jquery. Node.js or angular are not available.

Comment: What sort of async process?   JS processes (except for things like XHR) as typically not async.

Comment: "A global variable that is accesible for both functions" It wouldn't have to be global. It could be declared in a non-global scope which contains the scopes of the functions that need to access it. (Not that I'm recommending this approach.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using any external libs etc, a simple way would be using some form of encapsulation that returns you a stop method.

Here is a simple example.

```js
function doAsyncStuff() {
  var i = setInterval(function () {
    console.log("tick");
  }, 1000);
  return function stop() {
    console.log("Stop called");
    clearInterval(i);
  }
}


var stop = doAsyncStuff();


document.querySelector("button").onclick = stop;
```

```html
<button>Stop</button>
```

You could even extend this to return multiple functions, like resume restart etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something that uses events would work just fine.

```js
function main() {
  main.running = true
  doSomething()
}
function doSomething() {
 if (!input.checked) {
  console.log("checking")
  window.setTimeout(doSomething,1000);
 }
  else {
    main.running = false;
  }
  
}
function changeHandler(event) {
  if (event.target.checked == false && main.running == false) {
    main();
  }
}
var input = document.getElementById('check');
input.onchange=changeHandler;
main.running = false;
```

```html
<input id="check" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Keith version is better, since stop has a closure on doAsyncStuff, so you can use variables from doAsyncStuff in stop function